# How to delay to load the button on image view in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, button

I am new to iphone development. I have created a view controller and sets the button on the view. On clicking the button, it navigates to the next view and loaded the image in the view. Now i want to display the button on after loaded the image. The button will be shown after 3 seconds on the image view.

Please help me out,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

When the view loads, set the timer for 3 seconds and configure it to evoke a custom method of the view controller. That method should add the button to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Use NSTimer

In viewDidLoad

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

create a "updateCounter" custom method to display the button

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

display the button here...
}
```

All the Best.